# make BE API call when moving back from a fragment using onBackPressed()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

i have a fragment A, B and I have moved from fragment A to B.
now I am calling `activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed()` on fragment B to move back to fragment A.

on fragment A I have BE API calls in onResume() life cycle methods, but onResume() is not called when using onBackPressed()

could you please suggest how can I achieve this please. which Fragment lifecycle method will be called on fragment A when using `activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed()` to go back to previous fragment

Thanks
R

Comment: `Fragment.onResume()` is only called when `Activity.onResume()` is called. In the case of moving between `Fragment`s in an `Activity`, `onResume()` will not be called. How is your `Activity` handling the BACK button to navigate between `Fragment`s?